# Is this an ESP32 pin naming error?

Tags: esp32

Just looking at the datasheet for ESP32 I am finding something very strange.
I am trying to decipher why there is different pin assignment (for GPIO02) regarding my ESP32-WROVER and pin mux table inside document on page 60 (where it says it is attached on pin 22):

https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_datasheet_en.pdf

[image]

In the Wrover development kit schematic  it says the pin is located on pin 24:

https://dl.espressif.com/dl/schematics/ESP-WROVER-KIT_V4_1.pdf

[image]

Is this a mistake, am I looking at the wrong datasheet? I don't think so because there are no others.

Could some help out with this please?

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think the ESP32 datasheet gives the pinout for the ESP32 chip only, and the WROVER pinout is for the module, which includes the chip and other components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not just this pin - if you look, the others are also wrong in similar vein.

I think the datasheet you are reading has pin labels, which don't match up the ESP32 chip's pin labels. I.e. the first datasheet is the pinout of the ESP32 **chip**, while the second one is the ESP32-WROVER **module**. I.e. ESP pin #22, which is named GPIO2, is fanned out as pin #24 on the WROVER module.

Answer (score 2):

The ESP32 is a 48-pin QFN-packaged integrated circuit. Your first datasheet shows a pin-out of that, and it uses the standard pad numbering order (numbers increase counter-clockwise). Page 13 of the datasheet you linked gives a more visual version of your table, where you can in fact see that GPIO2 exits the part on pin 22:

[image: ESP32 Pinout]

The ESP-WROVER-KIT is a development board (see picture below:) that mounts an ESP32-WROVER *module*. The ESP32-WROVER contains an ESP32 chip underneath the shield, and has it wired to the edge of the PCB module. The numeric pin assignments don't need to be preserved (e.g. IO2 doesn't need to still come out of pin 24), you just need to know which pin IO2 was routed to in the module.

[image]

[image]